# NPM / Vite problem: Could not resolve "vue" in Framework7 project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vite

I'm having an unusual problem running a basic Framework7 project with vue.

Once created a `Framework7 Vue` project with the command: `framework7 create --ui` and installed the dependencies with `npm i` get the following problem: `Could not resolve "vue"`
in all packages because the script is looking for `vue` inside a `esm` folder like: `../../../node_modules/swiper/esm/vue/swiper.js:1:79` and it's quite strange because `esm` folder is never existed.

The strange thing is that the same project, with the same `package.json` works perfectly in another pc with the same version of node (`v16.14.2`) and npm (`8.7.0`)

So the problem must be in my pc. I thought about some cache problem, but despite forcing a cache cleanup the problem remains.

For completeness I leave the json package, which is the same that `framework7 create --ui`  command creates for a Vue project.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem or know what the cause might be?
I guess the problem could be related to `npm` or `vite`.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My App",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development vite",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production vite build && npx workbox generateSW workbox-config.js",
    "build-capacitor-ios": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production vite build && npx cap copy ios",
    "build-capacitor-android": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production vite build && npx cap copy android",
    "postinstall": "cpy --flat ./node_modules/framework7-icons/fonts/*.* ./src/fonts/ && cpy --flat ./node_modules/material-icons/iconfont/*.* ./src/fonts/"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "IOS >= 13",
    "Safari >= 13",
    "last 5 Chrome versions",
    "last 5 Firefox versions",
    "Samsung >= 12"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.4.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "^1.1.1",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^1.0.7",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.4.3",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.4.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^1.0.8",
    "dom7": "^4.0.4",
    "framework7": "^7.0.1",
    "framework7-icons": "^5.0.5",
    "framework7-vue": "^7.0.1",
    "material-icons": "^1.10.8",
    "skeleton-elements": "^4.0.0",
    "swiper": "^8.1.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.33"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.4.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.1",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.33",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.4",
    "cpy-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.5",
    "workbox-cli": "^6.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Changing in vite.config.js works for me. I have used the node_modules path for all the external bundle related errors

> You can mark the path "vue" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.

```
import path from 'path';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');
const PUBLIC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './public');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './www',);

function getPath(new_path) {
  return path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/' + new_path);
}

export default {
  plugins: [
    vue(),

  ],
  root: SRC_DIR,
  base: '',
  publicDir: PUBLIC_DIR,
  build: {
    outDir: BUILD_DIR,
    assetsInlineLimit: 0,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      treeshake: false,
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': SRC_DIR,
      "vue": getPath('vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-browser.js'),      
      "framework7/lite-bundle": getPath('framework7/framework7-lite-bundle.esm.js'),
      "framework7-vue/bundle": getPath('framework7-vue/framework7-vue-bundle.js'),
      "swiper/vue": getPath('swiper/vue/swiper-vue.js'),
      "skeleton-elements/vue": getPath('skeleton-elements/vue/index.js'),

    },
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
  },

};
```